# Credit card prediction in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, credit-card

I'm writing a tool that onkeydown will run the current value being entered in an input box to check to see if it matches a regex for one of the 4 major types of credit cards.

I feel like it kind of works, but it's flaky so I wanted to figure out what was causing it to give faulty response (e.g. sometimes it'll output 2 values instead of one). Is it because I need to set a flag variable before looping? Upon match of the correct card, I'm just returning from the loop through the object, so I thought that'd be sufficient enough...

The criteria for the regexes were pulled from [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html):

- **Visa**: `^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$` All Visa card numbers start with a 4. New cards have 16 digits. Old cards have 13.
- **MasterCard**: `^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$` All MasterCard numbers start with the numbers 51 through 55. All have 16 digits.
- **American Express**: `^3[47][0-9]{13}$` American Express card numbers start with 34 or 37 and have 15 digits.
- **Discover**: `^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$` Discover card numbers begin with 6011 or 65. All have 16 digits.

  ```
  $(function() {

  var $cardNumber = $('#js-cardnumber');

  var ccMap = {};

  ccMap.cards = {
      'amex': '^3[47][0-9]{13}$',
      'discover': '^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$',
      'mastercard': '^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$',
      'visa': '^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$'
  };


  $cardNumber.keydown(function() {
  for (var cardType in ccMap.cards) {
      if (ccMap.cards.hasOwnProperty(cardType)) {
          var regex = ccMap.cards[cardType];
          if (regex.match($(this).val())) {
              console.log(cardType);
              return;
          }
      }
  }
  });
  });​
  ```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/someprimetime/ThzXG/)

Comment: You are doing something wrong elsewhere. After logging to console you are exiting the procedure/ending the loop, so there is no chance for two log lines being outputted.

Comment: Check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn. And then this implementation is JS https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L1129

Comment: I would expect `/^3[47][0-9]{13)$/`

Comment: In fairness, I think they're doing card-type matching rather than luhn checking, so it isn't really reinventing the wheel. That said, since you'll want a luhn check too, and it will need to spin through ensuring each character is a digit, I'd take some luhn code and then add a length and prefix check onto it, rather than this approach.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, I've changed my regexes to follow that format. yeah this is basically just to show the image of the credit card. The actual validation is taking place server-side, so I don't think a Luhn would even be necessary. Thanks for the github link.

Comment: The title of this question is scary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're using the regular expressions in a wrong way.

If you want to check a string against a regular expression, you can use the `match()` method of the string:

```
string.match(regexp) // returns boolean
```

You're doing it the wrong way:

```
if ( regex.match($(this).val()) ) {
```

tries to interpret the current value as a regular expression. Must be this way:

```
if ( $(this).val().match(regex) ) {
```

---

You can also cache the regular expressions to make your script more efficient:

```
ccMap.cards = {
    'amex': /^3[47][0-9]{13}$/,  // store an actual regexp object, not a string
    // ...

// The way you test changes, now you're able to use the "test"
// method of the regexp object:
if ( regex.test($(this).val()) ) {
```

Comment: Oh dang. Thanks... Yeah that makes much more sense to store the regex itself rather than a string. Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: I find `match` confusing because every other regexp method works on the regex and `match` works on a string. I always use `exec` instead of `match` for this reason --> `regex.exec($(this).val())`